# get count and sum grouping dataframe by Pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, numpy, matplotlib

I have a sql table looks like this:

```
+----+------------+--------+------------+
| id | department | amount |    date    |
+----+------------+--------+------------+
| 1  | d1         |     20 | 2018-06-10 |
| 2  | d1         |     12 | 2018-06-10 |
| 2  | d1         |     10 | 2018-06-11 |
| 3  | d2         |     31 | 2018-06-10 |
| 4  | d2         |     42 | 2018-06-10 |
| 5  | d3         |     82 | 2018-06-11 |
| 6  | d3         |     11 | 2018-06-11 |
| 7  | d3         |     10 | 2018-06-14 |
+----+------------+--------+------------+
```

I read it with Pandas' `read_sql` method as:

```
df = pd.read_sql("select * table my_table", ...)
```

I want to plot time series of the data as the x axis will be day of month, and y axis is the count of department. So, I think I have to group them by day of month like

```
gdf = df.groupby(['department', pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='d')])['amount'].sum()
```

and gdf looks like:

```
department   date      
d1           2018-06-10      32
             2018-06-11      10
d2           2018-06-10      73
d3           2018-06-11      93
             2018-06-14      10
```

but, I do not know how I can use `gdf`. I would like to plot it with either seaborn or mathplotlib.

I also want to plot sum of amount grouped by day of month and department.

Note: Normally, I would edit my sql statement to have grouped data but in my case, I am not allowed to do so. I have to do this by using Pandas.

Comment: You should be using `Grouper` instead of `TimeGrouper`

Comment: Do you want one line plot per department, because there are multiple departments on a single day? Or, trying some other plot (like stacked bar plot)

Comment: I want to plot time series of each department on the same chart. In other words, for example, green line for d1, blue for d2 so on...

Comment: Will it be fine if instead of grouping by the department, for each unique department filter the data for that and sum it over daily and plot it?

Comment: yes, it would also work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For each unique department, summing 'amount' over day and plotting it on the same plot.

Firstly, `date` needs to be of `datetime` type before any Grouping based on it.

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

and then plotting the time-series as below:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))

for d in df['department'].unique():
    gdf = df[df['department']==d].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='d')).sum()
    ax.plot(gdf.index, gdf['amount'], label=d)

ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
plt.xticks(rotation=30)
fig.tight_layout()

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0), loc="upper right", bbox_transform=fig.transFigure,
           ncol=4, columnspacing=0.5)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The answer by DEEPAK SURANA is correct for graphing. However, it should be said that this will NOT work if your `df['date']` column has data of `str` type. I have added sample code for creating your DF below and converting `df['date']` column to `datetime` type.

```
import pandas as pd
data = [(1, 'd1', 20, '2018-06-10'),
        (2, 'd1', 12, '2018-06-10'),
        (2, 'd1', 10, '2018-06-11'),
        (3, 'd2', 31, '2018-06-10'),
        (4, 'd2', 42, '2018-06-10'),
        (5, 'd3', 82, '2018-06-11'),
        (6, 'd3', 11, '2018-06-11'),
        (7, 'd3', 10, '2018-06-14')]
labels = ['id', 'department', 'amount', 'date']
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns=labels)
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
```

Graphing code from DEEPAK SURANA:

> ```
> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
> import matplotlib.dates as mdates
> fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,6))
>
> for d in df['department'].unique():
>     gdf = df[df['department']==d].groupby(pd.Grouper(key='date', freq='d')).sum()
>     ax.plot(gdf.index, gdf['amount'], label=d)
>
> ax.get_xaxis().set_major_locator(mdates.DayLocator())
> ax.get_xaxis().set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%Y-%m-%d'))
> plt.xticks(rotation=30)
> fig.tight_layout()
>
> plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 0), loc="upper right", box_transform=fig.transFigure,
>            ncol=4, columnspacing=0.5)
> plt.show()
> ```

Comment: Yes, I agree that date needs to be in `datetime` format. But since `pd.Grouper()` worked for the `freq=d` in the question, I assumed that it's in right format.